# Verifying calibration process on IoT device, python script

Tags: python

I have an IoT device with accelerating and gyroscope sensors.
before my device can be used it needs to be calibrated.

Basically, it means that I do measures for XYZ axes and for the gyro movements and save the findings in
JSON file.

With this script, I want to assure the calibration process has occurred and that the values I got are in reasonable tolerance.

The axes' values divided between positive and negative and revolve around the value of 9.81 for the positive and -9.81 for the negative. When I say revolve I mean they should be in a certain tolerance.

The gyroscope values revolve around 0 with the same tolerance.

The default JSON file before it is being calibrated looks like this:

`{"acc_x_max": 9.81, "acc_x_min": -9.81, "acc_y_max": 9.81, "acc_y_min": -9.81, "acc_z_max": 9.81, "acc_z_min": -9.81, "gyro_x_offset": 0, "gyro_y_offset": 0, "gyro_z_offset": 0}`

I would like to have your great feedback about the most pythonic way and best practices for this script:

```
import logging
import sys

# Defining logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

# Defining constants
G = 9.81
TOLERANCE = 2.0
AXES_ARGS = ['acc_x_max', 'acc_y_max', 'acc_z_max', 'acc_x_min', 'acc_y_min', 'acc_z_min']
GYRO_OFFSETS = ['gyro_x_offset', 'gyro_y_offset', 'gyro_z_offset']
PATH_TO_CALIBRATION_FILE = '/home/pi/Desktop/device/IMU_calibration.json'
FIXING_CALIBRATION_MSG = 'please calibrated by running "sudo sh IoT/calibration.sh" ' \
                         'from /home/pi/Desktop/device directory '
CALIBRATION_ARGS = AXES_ARGS + GYRO_OFFSETS


def main():
    calib_dict = get_calibration_dictionary(PATH_TO_CALIBRATION_FILE)
    checking_if_calibration_file_has_been_changed(calib_dict)
    verify_calibration_in_tolerance_range()
    logger.info('Device is calibrated !!! :)')


def is_calibration_in_tolerance(data: str, tolerance: float, g_force: float):
    """
    This function takes a value and assesses if it stands in the calibration standards.
    @param g_force: float
    @param data: str - acc axes key or gyro offset key
    @param tolerance: the range which defines valid results in calibration accuracy.
    @return: None
    """
    calib_dict = get_calibration_dictionary(PATH_TO_CALIBRATION_FILE)
    if not abs(calib_dict[data] - g_force) <= tolerance:
        logger.error(data + f' seems out of calibration\n {FIXING_CALIBRATION_MSG}')
        exit(1)


def get_calibration_dictionary(path_to_calibration_file) -> dict:
    """
    This function verifying if the calibration file exists in the path and if it does;
    it returns the calibration data as a python dictionary.
    @param path_to_calibration_file: str - path to the calibration file.
    @return: python dictionary
    """
    try:
        with open(path_to_calibration_file) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f'cant find calibration file at: {path_to_calibration_file}')


def checking_if_calibration_file_has_been_changed(calib_dict: dict) -> None:
    calibration_file_did_not_change_error_msg = f'This Device hasn\'t been calibrated\n {FIXING_CALIBRATION_MSG}'

    # Checking if axes have been calibrated or they still hold their default values
    for axis in AXES_ARGS:
        if 'max' in axis and calib_dict[axis] == G:
            logger.error(calibration_file_did_not_change_error_msg)
            exit(1)
        if 'min' in axis and calib_dict[axis] == -G:
            logger.error(calibration_file_did_not_change_error_msg)
            exit(1)

    # Checking if gyro offsets have been calibrated or they still hold their default values
    for gyro_offset in GYRO_OFFSETS:
        if calib_dict[gyro_offset] == 0:
            logger.error(gyro_offset + calibration_file_did_not_change_error_msg)
            exit(1)


def verify_calibration_in_tolerance_range() -> None:
    """
    This function checks if the calibration values are in the tolerance range.
    It differentiates the input data according to its key and supplies "is_calibration_in_tolerance"
    function with suitable arguments.
    If the tested value does no meet the criteria it will exit with the return value of 1.
    If all the values meet the standard it returns None.
    @return: None
    """

    # verifying axes calibration in tolerance range
    for calib_key in CALIBRATION_ARGS:
        if 'max' in calib_key:
            is_calibration_in_tolerance(calib_key, TOLERANCE, G)
        elif 'min' in calib_key:
            is_calibration_in_tolerance(calib_key, TOLERANCE, -G)
        elif 'gyro' in calib_key:
            is_calibration_in_tolerance(calib_key, TOLERANCE, 0.0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This is not complete - you're missing at least one import

Comment: Could you specify them? I must have missed that and can't figure out which ones?

Comment: i see the JSON import :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using logging - great! You should encapsulate your logging setup so that you don't pollute the global namespace, something like

```
def make_logger():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)
    return logger

logger = make_logger()
```

The [standard value of gravitational acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_acceleration) at sea level is not 9.81 - it's 9.80665.

`AXES_ARGS` and `GYRO_OFFSETS` should be tuples instead of lists due to them being immutable.

`PATH_TO_CALIBRATION_FILE` is fine to take a value in `/home` *if the user provides that value in interactive mode*. But defaulting to something in `/home` is a bad idea. Since this seems like a permanent service on an IOT device, make an actual (non-`pi`) service user and pay attention to the recommendations for standard Unix file layout. Depending on a few things, your calibration file - if centralized - would be better in a permissions-restricted subdirectory of `/usr/share` or `/usr/local/share`, or maybe `/etc/` if it's considered "static configuration"; or maybe `/var/` if it's considered "runtime data". If it's not centralized and requires an interactive user (which seems unlikely), then you should just be accepting this path on the command line.

Grammar: `please calibrated` -> `please calibrate`

Asking that the user run `calibration.sh` under `sudo` is awful. Please don't contribute to the stereotype that IOT is a vast wasteland of insecurity - your user model needs to be cleaned up. Nothing in your calibration code should require root access.

This is basically a no-op:

```
    except FileNotFoundError:
        raise FileNotFoundError(f'cant find calibration file at: {path_to_calibration_file}')
```

so delete it and just let the original exception fall through.

Comment: This is extremely valuable THX